# Is this DML or DDL trigger?

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, ddl, dml

I wanted to ask if this is a DML or DDL Trigger ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INFORMATION_TIMEZONE
BEFORE INSERT ON information 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  

 IF (session_params.getCurrentRefperso) IS NOT NULL THEN
        :new.DT_HOUR_TIME_ZONE := current_timestamp();
 END IF;

END;
```

Comment: DML, firing condition (before insert) relates to table, not e.g. session or database.

Comment: Do you know what DML and DDL stand for? If you do, you should be able to work it out quite easily. If you don't, you've not done enough research before asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `BEFORE INSERT` defines this trigger to be fired when an `INSERT` is done.

As `INSERT` is a DML statement, the trigger is a DML trigger.

A DDL trigger would e.g. have `BEFORE CREATE` or `BEFORE DROP` in the trigger definition.